# Can't get an application context in my spock spring test

Tags: spring-boot, spock

The following test fails, and I can see in the logs that there is simply no application context being built. But what am I missing here?

```
package my.dwh.etl

import my.dwh.DwhApplication
import groovy.util.logging.Log
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import spock.lang.Specification

    @Log
    @SpringBootTest(classes = DwhApplication.class)
    class ETL_IT extends Specification {

        @Autowired
        ApplicationContext context

        def "test integration of loading StackedWithHeaderAndAllTypesSource and storing into h2"() {

            given:
            def a

            when:
            a = 1

            then:
            context != null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on your class

Comment: that gives `no runnable methods` exception as this would expect JUnit test but its a spock test

Comment: Your class doesn't end with `Spec`, missed it.

Comment: Indeed this is it! I always thought test need to end *Test or *IT

Comment: Added same as an answer.

Comment: By default maven surefire uses `Test*`/`*Test` and failsafe uses `*IT` so it should have worked in maven. You have probably reconfigured surefire/failsafe to only scan for `*Spec` by setting```<includes>
            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
</includes>``` If you want to change it back you can either just delete the setting or add the old patterns back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spock tests find classes whose names end with the suffix: `Spec`. You have to create the name of our Spock specification class by following this rule: `[The name of the tested/specified unit]Spec`